# 22.04 - macvlan module missing?

Tags: networking, 22.04, lxc, lxd

I am trying to copy some lxd containers from a raspberry pi running Ubuntu 20.04 to a raspberry pi running 22.04. The containers use macvlan, which produces the following error if I try to run the container:

```
Error: Failed to start device "eth1": Failed to run: ip link add mac81f2ac4a link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge: Error: Unknown device type.
```

Had a look with `lsmod` and on the pi running 20.04 I see the `macvlan` module, but not on 22.04. Have tried updating and restarting but to no avail.

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:
`sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi`
The macvlan module is now available.